# How much time to generate a proof in ZK-snark?

Tags: zero-knowledge-proofs

I know that zk-SNARK takes in range of milliseconds to verify statements. But what about the time to generate the proof. For example, if I have a circuit that tests the `There is key s.t H(key)=s`

Thanks for anyone offers help in this question since I need an answer to it urgently in my thesis.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just run example code from [ZoKrates manual](https://github.com/Zokrates/ZoKrates/blob/develop/zokrates_book/src/sha256example.md) and measured time and memory usage.

Here is how "proof of preimage" problem defined in ZoKrates:

```
def main(field a, field b, field c, field d) -> (field):
    h0, h1 = sha256packed(a, b, c, d)
    h0 == 263561599766550617289250058199814760685
    h1 == 65303172752238645975888084098459749904
    return 1
```

For such a simple program:

- setup takes ~20 seconds and ~350 Mb memory;
- generating witness and proof takes <5 seconds and ~150 Mb memory.

For something more complex like proving UTXO in ZCash proving may take tens of seconds and couple of gigabytes (see [here](https://z.cash/blog/cultivating-sapling-faster-zksnarks/)).

---

Following steps are required to run the proving protocol.

**1.** Compile human readable code into arithmetic circuits (~7 seconds, ~240 Mb):

```
$ time zokrates compile -i hashexample.code
2.08user 5.14system 0:07.24elapsed 99%CPU (0avgtext+0avgdata 238044maxresident)k
0inputs+21641416outputs (0major+70866minor)pagefaults 0swaps
```

Generated arithmetic circuit is 15Mb.

**2.** Trusted setup (~15 seconds, 350 Mb)

```
$ time zokrates setup
13.73user 0.94system 0:14.68elapsed 99%CPU (0avgtext+0avgdata 354912maxresident)k
0inputs+66248outputs (0major+90965minor)pagefaults 0swaps
```

On this step proving key (32Mb) and verifying key (2.6Kb) are generated.

**3.** Computing witness from known arguments (~1 second, ~150 Mb)

```
$ time zokrates compute-witness -a 0 0 0 5
0.82user 0.92system 0:01.75elapsed 99%CPU (0avgtext+0avgdata 148620maxresident)k
0inputs+1440outputs (0major+39469minor)pagefaults 0swaps
```

Witness is 458 Kb in size.

**4.** Generating the proof (~3 seconds, ~106 Mb)

```
$ time zokrates generate-proof
2.71user 0.06system 0:02.78elapsed 99%CPU (0avgtext+0avgdata 106188maxresident)k
0inputs+40outputs (0major+36676minor)pagefaults 0swaps
```

The proof is 1.4 Kb in size.

Comment: I really want to thank you. you saved me. I have another question if statement I want to verify using ZK-SNARk include encryption operation as `There is key s.t H(key)=s  and   H(Dec(U,key))= Ui` .  Can we get the time to generate a proof for the previous statement?

Comment: Couldn't find any SNARKified encryption algorithm, but I think it is safe to assume that decryption circuit size is comparable to the hashing circuit.
So I checked double hashing: compile and setup takes 50sec and 700Mb, proof generation takes 10sec and 230Mb.
For triple hasing it is 70sec, 1Gb and 14sec, 320Mb respectively.

Comment: What about the verification time in zokrtes ?

Comment: Verification is almost instant as it O(1) and does not depend on circuit size.

Comment: Is there is any code to determine the time of verification of a proof ??

Comment: https://github.com/jstoxrocky/zksnarks_example#output-from-zokrates-export-verifier-command

Comment: Oh that is good example. Do you have any idea if zokrtes supports statements with encryption or signatures like RSA ?